# Rs mutate() and grepl() in Python

Tags: python, r, grepl, mutate

I have a column in a dataset that lists all of the softwares that a given computer has installed. I have created multiple binary columns from this column so each software has its own column. My R code is below:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(MS_Office_installed = ifelse(grepl("MS Office", installed_software), 1, 0),
         Adobe_Acrobat_installed = ifelse(grepl("Adobe Acrobat", installed_software), 1, 0),
         Slack_installed = ifelse(grepl("Slack", installed_software), 1, 0),
         Mathcard_installed = ifelse(grepl("Mathcard", installed_software), 1, 0),
         Google_Chrome_installed = ifelse(grepl("Google Chrome", installed_software), 1, 0))
```

How can I duplicate this in Python? Some observations have no softwares installed and have NaN

Comment: Are you trying to port this logic over to Pandas?  Can you include your Python script?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have the same dataframe in Python, I have no code for this yet as I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `str.contains` here.  For example:

```py
df["MS_Office_installed"] = df["installed_software"].str.contains(r'\bMS Office\b', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Use similar logic for the other desired boolean columns.

Comment: I'm getting an error because the column contains NaNs, is there a way to assign 0 for the observations that have NaN?

Comment: never mind, I changed NaNs to "None" and it worked perfect, thanks!